# Wo soll "sich" im Satz stehen

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

Wo soll sich "sich" befinden

> Da er sich nur in Andeutungen ergeht, kann er sich allenfalls die
> Gunst der Entscheidungsträger erschleichen.

oder eher

> Da er sich nur in Andeutungen ergeht, kann er allenfalls sich die
> Gunst der Entscheidungsträger erschleichen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are right with slight nuances in emphasis:

If you want to put emphasis on "allenfalls": choose 1st sentence. "at most" is important.

If you want to put emphasis on "sich": choose 2nd sentence. "for himself but not anyone else" is important